# последовательный вызов тестов GROOVY

Tags: groovy

Есть класс с тестами, необходимо последовательно их вызвать, но с разными данными.

например:

```
Class A {

 list l = {Param1, Param2}

def "test1"(){
    when:
     def x = "x"
    then:
     println x 
 }

def "test2"(){
    when:
     def y = "y"
    then:
     println y  
 }
}
```

Код максимально абстрактный и не имеет смысла, просто для понимания ситуации.
Так вот, мне необходимо, чтобы для param1 прогнались тесты в строгом порядке 1->2 и затем я делаю cleanup и для Param2 таким же образом запустились тесты 1 -> 2. Всё это нужно чтобы избежать кучи абстрактных классов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может кому это и поможет, но нашел вариант:

1. делаем класс со статическими методами
2. затем создаем класс с тестовыми методами.
3. в тестовом классе пишем примерно так:

   ```
    @Unroll
    def "Test #name" () {
      setup: настраиваем необходимое

      expect:
      АбстрактныйКласс.метод1(data)
      АбстрактныйКласс.метод2(data)

      cleaup: чистим

      where:
      data           | name
      нашиПараметры  | имяТеста
   ```

   }